# How can we use YouTube videos in mobile application

Tags: android, youtube, google-play-services, android-youtube-api

I built a small education app useful for kids. So i map subjects and concepts like below:

[image]

Then a kid can click on the link, then in the next activity I am streaming YouTube video in YouTubePlayer:

```
<FrameLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    >

    <com.google.android.youtube.player.YouTubePlayerView
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:id="@+id/youtubePlayerID"
         android:layout_marginTop="35dp"
         android:gravity="center"
        />

    <ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@mipmap/close_32" />


</FrameLayout>
```

[image: YouTubeActivity]

Then i am using below code to play the video in above YouTubePlayerView:

```
ypView.initialize(strYoutubeKey, new YouTubePlayer.OnInitializedListener() {
           @Override
            public void onInitializationFailure(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubeInitializationResult result) {
                Log.d("onInitializationFailure","Unable to load");
            }

            @Override
            public void onInitializationSuccess(YouTubePlayer.Provider provider, YouTubePlayer player, boolean wasRestored) {
               if(!wasRestored)
                player.loadVideo(**strVideoURL**);
                //player.cueVideo(strVideoURL,1);
            }
        });
```

The **strVideoURL** is any video URL corresponds to the topic developed by creators available in YouTube(Ex: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=_B5dhVPeqSg for the first topic from above picture)

I have published this app in Playstore and now Google has removed the app from Playstore.

I follow up with them couple of times and they replied saying below:
Thanks for reaching out to the Google Play Team.

> We reviewed your app (com.udayrepo.classelearn) and the initial
>   takedown decision was confirmed. Your app will not be reinstated
>   because it violates our Device and Network Abuse policy by
>   downloading, monetizing, or otherwise accessing YouTube videos in
>   violation of the YouTube Terms of Service or YouTube API Terms of
>   Service.
>
> **> For example, your app is able to stream copyrighted works from YouTube
>   illegally.**
>
> You'll need to make changes to your app before submitting it for
>   another review. If you choose to submit your app again, you may want
>   to review the Device and Network Abuse policy and the Developer
>   Program Policies for additional guidance.
>
> Please let me know if you have any other questions.

1. Can someone help what is the right way to use YouTube videos in our app?
2. When a kid clicks on the link, cant we play that video in our app?
3. Can i redirect that video directly play in YouTube and not in my app.

Suggest me better which i can do.

Looking forward all your help.

Comment: Is your app showing any add in banner or footer etc while playing YouTube ? Also, how is ur app playing the videos using ytube player?

Comment: Hi @Salah-1, I am not displaying any Ads in YouTube activity. You can observe from the above screenshot and also in the code that, there is no Ad at all. There is only a close button. Upon clicking on that button, redirecting back to topic selection activity as shown in first image.

Comment: Can anyone help me on my above problem? My app is removed from Playstore and i am loosing my active users. Looking forward your help.

Comment: is your problem solved?? is redirection allowed from your app to youtube???

Comment: Hi @Uday, have you solved the issue? Thanks for response.

Answer (score 0):

The device and network abuse policy of Youtube can be very vague. Below are few possibilities of why the rejection, but i suggest **emailing** them back and say, "please be specific as to what the issue is".

Although, in **your case**, they highlighted the part in your post (bold) which i think they referring to.

Examples of policy violation as per the policy

Here are some examples of common violations:

```
Apps that block or interfere with another app displaying ads.
Game cheating apps that affect the gameplay of other apps.
Apps that facilitate or provide instructions on how to hack services, software or hardware, or circumvent security protections.
Apps that access or use a service or API in a manner that violates its terms of service.
Apps that attempt to bypass system power management that are not eligible for whitelisting.
```

**In your case**, focus on the following and find out if your app is doing any of it(taken from their response as you posted).

..by downloading, monetizing, or otherwise accessing YouTube videos in violation of the YouTube Terms of Service.

.... For example, your app is able to stream copyrighted works from YouTube illegally.

Here are few references beginning with the Device and Network Abuse policy itself.

https://play.google.com/about/privacy-security-deception/device-network-abuse/

https://www.reddit.com/r/androiddev/comments/9qebyl/strike_due_to_a_very_vague_violation_of_device/

[How to fix the Device and Network abuse policy issue in Google play store app submission](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/41311473/how-to-fix-the-device-and-network-abuse-policy-issue-in-google-play-store-app-su)

If after looking over your app and what's written above, it doesn't give you good idea of why, then email Play Store asking more specific details.

Comment: Thanks Salah for taking time to write this response. I have replied to their mail asking for more information. I am not doing any of the above violations(which i am aware of). What i dont know is, is every video posted in YouTube is copyrighted or are there any specific videos which are copy righted which we should not use in our app? Can anyone suggest me, is there any problem in my above approach(Code or Layout)? I am just using player and youtube video is streamed in that player. No Ads in that activity. Whatelse i am missing?

Comment: I'm curious to know how you went with this? Do you need to link out to the youtube app or website to satisfy the terms and conditions?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the imageview, one cannot put anything on top of the youtube player this might be the reason your app is rejected. Remove the below code and your app will be accepted I guess.

```
<ImageView
        android:id="@+id/closeLayout"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_gravity="top|right"
        android:adjustViewBounds="true"
        android:scaleType="fitStart"
        android:src="@mipmap/close_32" />
```